# Inserting data to elasticsearch according to mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created a mapping:

```
request_body = {
    'settings': {
        'number_of_shards': 3,
        'number_of_replicas': 2
    },
    'mappings': {
        'dynamic': 'strict',
        'properties': {
            'content': {'index': True, 'type': 'text'},
            'location': {'type': 'geo_point'},
            'retweet_count': {'type': 'integer'},
            'favorite_count': {'type': 'integer'},
            'happened_at': {'type': 'date'},
            'author': {
                'properties': {
                    'id': {'type': 'integer'},
                    'screen_name': {'type': 'text'},
                    'name': {'type': 'text'},
                    'description': {'index': True, 'type': 'text'},
                    'followers_count': {'type': 'integer'},
                    'friends_count': {'type': 'integer'},
                    'statuses_count': {'type': 'integer'}
                }
            },
            'country': {
                'properties': {
                    'id': {'type': 'integer'},
                    'code': {'type': 'text'},
                    'name': {'type': 'text'}
                }
            },
            'parent_id': {'type': 'integer'},
            'mentions': {
                'type': 'nested',
                'properties': {
                    'id': {'type': 'integer'},
                    'screen_name': {'type': 'text'},
                    'name': {'type': 'text'}
                }
            },
            'hashtags': {
                'type': 'nested',
                'properties': {
                    'id': {'type': 'integer'},
                    'value': {'type': 'text'}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then I create an index: `es.indices.create(index='pdt', body=request_body)`, where es is instance of elasticsearch in python.

Then I want to insert a dictionary using bulk insert, the dictionary:

```
   '_id' = {str} '1290712423939346432'
   '_source' = {dict}  
      'content' = {str} 'RT @drfahrettinkoca: YENİ HASTA SAYISINDAKİ YÜKSELME CİDDİ. İki gün arasındaki fark, yakın zamanda ilk kez bu kadar belirgin. Bayram ve tat…'
      'location' = {NoneType} None
      'retweet_count' = {int} 9556
      'favorite_count' = {int} 0
      'happened_at' = {str} '2020-08-04 20:13:16+02:00'
      'author' = {dict}  
      'parent_id' = {str} '1290699635003133953'
      'mentions' = {list}  
      'hashtags' = {list}
```

The only item that is not present is the country, which can be None. I tried with both `country = None` and

```
'country': {
   'id': None,    
   'code': None,    
   'name': None,
}
```

So I am not sure where the problem could be. Is passing an empty list a problem?
Here is the error code:

```
('1 document(s) failed to index.', [{'index': {'_index': 'pdt', '_type': 'tweet', '_id': '1290712423939346432', 'status': 400, 'error': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'cannot change object mapping from nested to non-nested'}, 'data': {'content': 'RT @drfahrettinkoca: YENİ HASTA SAYISINDAKİ YÜKSELME CİDDİ. İki gün arasındaki fark, yakın zamanda ilk kez bu kadar belirgin. Bayram ve tat…', 'location': None, 'retweet_count': 9556, 'favorite_count': 0, 'happened_at': '2020-08-04 20:13:16+02:00', 'author': {'id': 794067571226066944, 'screen_name': 'zonguldak_ism', 'name': 'Zonguldak İSM', 'description': 'Adres:Yayla Mah. Ömer Karahasan Sok. No:6 Merkez/ZONGULDAK Telefon:+90 372 253 4607 Fax:+90 372 253 0667', 'followers_count': 703, 'friends_count': 91, 'statuses_count': 1446}, 'parent_id': '1290699635003133953', 'mentions': [{'id': 3679748, 'screen_name': 'drfahrettinkoca', 'name': 'Dr. Fahrettin Koca'}], 'hashtags': []}}}])
```

Comment: If the country doesn't exist, can you try `'country': None` instead?

Comment: I tried this, it turns out I was specifying a document type which doesn't exist.

Comment: you mean `tweet`?

Comment: Yes, I removed this in the helper.bulk insert. Now I have a problem with date format, as mine is in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+HH:mm`, e.g. `2020-08-04 20:13:16+02:00`.

Comment: The right format should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: I got this error instead `"failed to parse field [happened_at] of type [date] in document with id '1290712423939346432'. Preview of field's value: '2020-08-04 20:13:16+02:00'", 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'failed to parse date field [2020-08-04 20:13:16+02:00] with format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ]', 'caused_by': {'type': 'date_time_parse_exception', 'reason': "date_time_parse_exception: Text '2020-08-04 20:13:16+02:00' could not be parsed at index 19"}}` I believe the problem is that the "date" is in text form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225363/discussion-between-michael-krocka-and-val).

Comment: Actually the format needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`